# How to handle microseconds with 7 decimal precision instead of 6

Tags: python, strptime

I am processing a csv in `python` (3.5) that has a date field in it.  The date contains a microsecond precision of 7 rather than 6, which I believe is the max that `strptime` can handle.

Without stripping the field the last character, is there a way to make this a datetime object?

Here is the specific code:

```
d = '2015-07-03 17:29:34.5940379'
pd.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 9
```

Comment: You must be American...

Comment: @StefanPochmann I laughed

Comment: Ok good :-). And I must be tired, btw, joking about Americans not knowing the metric system but actually I myself just confused micro with milli until I saw @cco's answer... ouch. Anyway, at least 7 digits is neither milli nor micro, so I call it a tie :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's the format your numbers are in, just use `pd.to_timestamp(d)`

datetime.datetime objects only have microsecond resolution (6 digits), but [Pandas Timestamps](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#converting-to-timestamps) are Numpy datetime64 objects.